# Mirror API PHP sample scripts: how to trigger timeline inserts

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I installed [the Mirror API sample scripts (PHP)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/mirror) on my (non-ssl) webserver and made some changes to it so it inserts some interesting solar panel data on my Google Glass timeline. Works fine. The adapted sample script now inserts a card on the timeline when I access this PHP web page using a web browser.

My next step would be to insert cards at a regular time interval or by some kind of trigger (e.g. voice command) but certainly not by accessing this web page using a web browsr. I am clearly missing out on something because I still don't see how to go about this... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a php guy, but the idea is same in general.

1. When user comes to your site, your responsibility is to grant access, via OAUTH2 (as far as I can see you successfully passed that step)
2. When oauth dance finished, your responsibility is to save access_token and verify_token + userId + etc. to the database. (it should also be done, in a google sample)
3. To get periodical updates will require you to write some peace of code, for instance:

   1. Windows Service(deploy it somewhere, or run on localhost(not recommended, btw)) + Time Scheduler
   2. bash scripts
   3. web rest services
   4. something else
      and get it up an running in schedule using for instance

**cron jobs** (raw idea: http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/cron-job-on-google-app-engine-for-java/ )

where you have to use **Mirror Api** libraries, provided for language you accepts, or do cook a raw HTTP requiests, as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline

Comment: Hi Eugene thanks responding. Indeed, step 1 and 2 are accomplished. I also know how to write bash scripts and schedule cron jobs. My problem is that if I want to activate the PHP script from a cron job, I have to activate is using a command line browser such as Lynx. Lynx cannot do the oAuth dance because of the JavaScript submit button in the oAuth proces. So I am trying to find an other way to do activate my PHP script. Or another construction to regularly insert cards on the glass timeline. Is this only going to work when subscriptions are possible (SSL session)?

Comment: @user3446336  as soon as user authorized own GG on your site(via magic button), you have all you need. Oauth dance no longer required, because you have the access_key and verify_key in database, so do direct call, using these keys. One problem you may catch here is expiration of access_key(Google set up expire time ~ 1h, tiny time). But even this is not a problem for Mirror libs provided by google, because if that case happens, lib will handle it without your input.

Comment: @user3446336 SSL is surely preferable, some hack has been provided by google - forward proxy - more information here https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/subscription-proxy

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks again, you are right and I am getting there. I changed the mirror-client.php, in the function subscribe-to-notifications" I set $subscription-> setCallbackUrl('https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=myserverurl/notify.php');". After this change the subscription works and now I finally can perform server side initiated updates of the timeline. Beginning to grasp the concept :-) -Note: the https disappears in the url above-